# How does one reduce the speech rate in the Read Text Extension in Libreoffice?

Tags: sound, video, libreoffice, totem, text-to-speech

I installed read text extension for libreoffice. I want to slow down the speech rate. I opened up `->tools->add ons->read selection` and discovered the following popup menu

```
#read with an external program
/usr/bin/python2.7
#command line options
"(ESPEAK_READ_TEXT_PY)" --language=(SELECTION_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY_CODE) --output "(HOME)(NOW).wav" "(TMP)"
```

The following command above opens up totem video and plays the temporary prerecord audio file of the selected text. I am unable to find a reduce audio play rate option in Totem Video. I changed my default programs to VLC, which did not effect the above code. I added the line `vlc` next to `--output`, which did not open vlc.

How does one reduce the speech rate in the Read Text Extension in Libreoffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify a file installed by the Read text extension, `espeak_read_text_file.py`.

First locate this file on your system:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate espeak_read_text_file.py
/home/sylvain/.config/libreoffice/4/user/extensions/tmp/extensions/lukglria.tmp_/read_text.0.8.20.oxt/python/espeak_read_text_file.py
/home/sylvain/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lukglrib.tmp_/read_text.0.8.20.oxt/python/espeak_read_text_file.py
```

Open the one located in `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages`.

Line 155 you should see a command like the one below:

```
s1='"'+sCommand+'" -v '+sVoice+' -w "'+sTMP1+'" '+sTXT
```

Change it for this one instead:

```
s1='"'+sCommand+'" -s 120 -v '+sVoice+' -w "'+sTMP1+'" '+sTXT
```

This will use the `-s <integer>` option of `espeak` (Speed in words per minute, default is 160)

### linuxfreebird's additional note

The code is space sensitive.

```
    if "windows" in platform.system().lower():
      sCommand=readtexttools.getWinFullPath("eSpeak/command_line/espeak.exe")
#    s1='"'+sCommand+'" -v '+sVoice+' -w "'+sTMP1+'" '+sTXT
    s1='"'+sCommand+'" -s 140 -v '+sVoice+' -w "'+sTMP1+'" '+sTXT
    readtexttools.myossystem(s1)
    readtexttools.ProcessWaveMedia(sB,sTMP1,sIMG1,sOUT1,sAUDIBLE,sVISIBLE)
```

Make sure that the line starting with `s1` is inline with the `readtexttools` indicated in the code above. If their is a space misalignment, the code will not execute correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I am very surprised that there is no one click fix for this. It seems odd that the average user would have to modify internal code to simply slow down the speech rate.

Comment: I added a small fix to a small problem I discovered that other people might run into as I did. Feel free to edit or delete. Thanks.

Comment: @linuxfreebird thanks for the edit. You have indeed to follow the python indentation.

Comment: By the way, where I can get better voice syntheses for espeek? The default voice leaves much to desire.

Answer (score 2):

From reading above and studying the correct file I found I could change the rate and the pitch in the **Read Text dialog box**.  I didn't modify the file itself.  I just added `--rate=35% --pitch=65%` into the code in the dialog box.

`"(PICO_READ_TEXT_PY)" --language=(SELECTION_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY_CODE) --visible=false --rate=35% --pitch=65%  "(TMP)"`

See a screen capture of the Read Text dialog box with added code here:
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTW7E.png]

Comment: It would be more obvious to end users if the developers of Read Text would add this little bit of extra code into the dialog box in the first place, but they appear to be very difficult to contact.  " --rate=100% --pitch=100%"

Comment: How do you bring up this dialog?  It doesn't show up for me automatically anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions above, this helped me realize that, at least in the lastest version (Read Text 0.8.70), the developers have offered a number of selectable options in the field 'Command line options', such as:

"(TTS_WSCRIPT_VBS)" /language:"(SELECTION_LANGUAGE_COUNTRY_CODE)" /rate:-2 "(TMP)".

to change reading speed. The rate goes from 0 (apparently no change) to -10 (unbearably slow). You can speed up with positive integers.
It also has all the rate options for French. Nice!